# MySQL Issues Inserting Multiple Rows with One Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I realize there are similar topics on this, many in fact, but none of them are helping me figure out my issue and it just seems to lead me farther and farther from my goal. I have tried implode, for each, loops, etc., but either I receive "Query was empty" because I am passing empty array or else I get a syntax error.

I am using mysqli prepared statements and here is what I have tried working with with no luck. Very stumped. Basically, I am inserting potentially many ingredient rows passed from an API I have built:

API URL string

```
menu_item.php?ingredient_name[]=bacon&ingredient_price[]=1.00&ingredient_default[]=0&ingredient_name[]=cheese&ingredient_price[]=0&ingredient_default[]=1
```

PHP

```
// set arrays, item_id, foreign key, already set from previous query
    $ingredient_name = $_GET['ingredient_name'];
    $ingredient_price = $_GET['ingredient_price'];
    $ingredient_default = $_GET['ingredient_default'];
    // define arrays
    $ingredients = array(
        'ingredient_name' => $ingredient_name,
        'ingredient_price' => $ingredient_price,
        'ingredient_default' => $ingredient_default
    );
    $insertQuery = array();
    $insertData = array();
    // set array length
    $len = count($ingredients);
    /**
    prepare the array values for mysql
    **/
    // prepare values to insert recursively
    $ingQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE (column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES ";
    // set placeholders
    foreach ($ingredients as $row) {
        $insertQuery[] = '(?,?,?,?)';
    }
    // iterate through all available data
    for( $i=0;$i<$len;$i++ ) {
        $insertData[] = $ingredients['ingredient_name'][$i];
        $insertData[] = $ingredients['ingredient_price'][$i];
        $insertData[] = $ingredients['ingredient_default'][$i];
    }
    // set ingredient value placeholders
    $ingQuery .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    // prepare statement ingredients
    $ingStmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    // run the query
    if( $ingStmt ) {
        $ingStmt->execute($insertData);
    } else {
        // handle error return
        echo json_encode(array('error' => $mysqli->error.__LINE__));
        echo json_encode($insertData);
    }
```

For now ignore all that maybe I need to start over. Any suggestions? Currently I am receiving Query Was Empty error... I need to do this a better, more efficient way, but I am scratching my head on this!

**EDIT (still in progress)**

```
// the query
    $ingQuery = "INSERT INTO table (column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    // prepare statement
    $ingStmt = $mysqli->prepare($ingQuery);
    if( $ingStmt ) {
        // iterate through all available data
        for( $i=0;$i<count($_GET['ingredient_name']);$i++ ) {
            $ingStmt->execute(array($item_id,$_GET['ingredient_name'][$i],$_GET['ingredient_price'][$i],$_GET['ingredient_default'][$i]));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => $mysqli->error.__LINE__));
    }
    $ingStmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have 4 columns in your query - `(column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`, but you are only inserting 3 values `$_GET['ingredient_name'], $_GET['ingredient_price'], $_GET['ingredient_default']`

Second, unless you need to reuse your arrays/variables, why not simplify it down to the prepare and execute in a loop -

```
// the query
$ingQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)";
// prepare statement
$ingStmt = $mysqli->prepare($ingQuery);
// iterate through all available data
for( $i=0;$i<count($_GET['ingredient_name']);$i++ ) {
    $ingStmt->execute(array($_GET['ingredient_name'][$i], $_GET['ingredient_price'][$i], $_GET['ingredient_default'][$i]));
}
```

---

**update**
You need to use `bind_param()` when using mysqli -

```
// the query
$ingQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE (column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
// prepare statement
$ingStmt = $mysqli->prepare($ingQuery);
$ingStmt->bind_param("isss", $item_id, $val1, $val2, $val3);
// iterate through all available data
for( $i=0;$i<count($_GET['ingredient_name']);$i++ ) {
    $val1 = $_GET['ingredient_name'][$i];
    $val2 = $_GET['ingredient_price'][$i];
    $val3 = $_GET['ingredient_default'][$i];
    $ingStmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: i am supposed to be submitting 4 because of item_id, is the insertData[] wrong? Item_id is only ever one value, not an array, but do I need to make it part of the array now?

Comment: Yes, `insertData[]` is wrong as it is only containing 3 items, as it is does not include the `item_id`. I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated my question and did exactly as you instructed, but now I am not getting an error and still no data in the database table... =/ and actually item_id is not an array from the API string, it is only inherited from another parent table's insert statement in the same PHP script. I end up defining the item_id variable by `$item_id = $mysqli->insert_id;`

Comment: After looking at the docs for [`mysqli->execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php), I realized that you cannot put the parameters in the execute call, which you can using PDO. You need to use [`mysqli->bind_param()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). I have updated my example.

Comment: You're a lifesaver man... it's really simple once you brought it to light. sigh. I need to look into PDO instead of O-O MySQLi. PDO seems like it can make things like this alot easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect

```
// set array length
$len = count($ingredients);
```

Your $ingredients array will always have 3 elements regardless. Try this instead:

```
// set array length
$len = count($ingredient_name);
```

Then, this is incorrect (there is no variable called $sql)

```
$ingStmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
```

It should be

```
$ingStmt = $mysqli->prepare($ingQuery);
```